# Replacing <li> with <li style="color:green"> when <li> lies between <span style="color:green"> and </span>

Tags: php, regex

I have input string that could contain the span tag with color green in it's styling tag many times. I want that whenever li tag is present in between the opening and closing span tag, it's styling should be color:green. 
My input:

```
  This is the <span style="color:green"> whatever <li> input </li> anystring</span>. 
  This is second <span style="color:green"> whatever2 <li> input2 </li> any string2</span>.
```

In my output I want all li tags should be replaced by:

```
 <li style="color:green">
```

Output should be:

```
  This is the <span style="color:green"> whatever <li style="color:green"> input </li> anystring</span>. 
  This is second <span style="color:green"> whatever2 <li style="color:green"> input2 </li> any string2</span>.
```

I tried doing it through preg_replace, but it is not working in the way I want. There is definitely some problem in my symbols.

Comment: Any reason why you're doing the replace this way? I'd suggest not using inline styles. Add a class to the ones you want styled a particular way and define the styles in CSS.

Comment: I need to use inline styling because it needs to be displayed in email and in emails we have to define inline styling.

Comment: So basically, if li tags occur (that doesn't already have green style) inside span tags that have green styling, replace them with li tags that have green styling, correct?

Comment: Yes, whenever li tag appears between span, it does not style it automatically, so I have to do it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

Search: `(<span style="color:green">.*?)<li>([^<>]+</li>.*?</span>)`

Replace with: `$1<li style="color:green">$2`

https://regex101.com/r/dZ2mL4/1